# How do I get the name of the user using Gmail API for Android?

Tags: android, rest, gmail-api

I am creating an Android Application in which I am providing Gmail Login. I need to get the name of the user. I am taking help from the tutorial provided by Google to integrate Gmail (Link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android#step_5_setup_the_sample)

I don't have any experience of using REST APIs. Can anyone tell me how do I get the name?

Answer (score 0):

By name do you mean email address/username or the name of the User. if you are looking for email then you can get it using the `Users:getProfile` [Class](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/profile
```

Sample Response:

```
{
"emailAddress": string,
"messagesTotal": integer,
"threadsTotal": integer,
"historyId": unsigned long
}
```

BUT if you are trying to get the name of the user, you can try [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and
// basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestEmail()
.build();

// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to GoogleSignIn.API and the options above.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this, this)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
.build();
```

Then, when the sign-in button is clicked, start the sign-in intent:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The user is prompted to select a Google account to sign in with. If you requested scopes beyond profile, email, and `openid`, the user is also prompted to grant access to the requested resources.

Finally, handle the activity result:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

// Result returned from launching the Intent from
// GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
// Get account information
mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
mEmail = acct.getEmail();
}
}
}
```

HTH